# Android SQL database open and close - race condition

Tags: java, android, mysql, multithreading

I have quite a complex app that reads and writes to the database from all sort of background threads and services. Sometimes (and unfortunately quite often) I get crashes with

> attempt to re-open an already-closed object

and

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because
>   the connection pool has been closed.

I've read through a few SO questions on this topic and the general advice ranges from not closing db connection at all, closing/opening onCreate/onResume, closing/opening in Application, closing/opening when you need to perform an operation on the database etc.

Last thing I tried was moving all my open/close into actual methods that work with the db objects. That reduced the frequency of errors however I'm still getting problems when 2 different methods are accessed from different threads, both open the db but one closes the connection when the second one is just about to run a query and expects the db to be opened.

I know I could synchronize on a common lock object as my DB manager class that includes all my db access methods is a singleton, however it feels bad to do that just for open/close.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to synchronize your db methods then maintain the count for number of open and close method calls like below.

```
int count=0;

openDb(){
  if(db==null){
        //Open the db
   }
   count++;
}

public void closeDb(){
        count--;
        if(count==0){
            //close the db
        }
}
```

Comment: You would still need to employ some kind of locks. 
E.g. I have 2 threads and `count`= 1. Then one thread calls `openDb` and gets past the `if` but is interrupted before ot can complete the `count++`: the database is already open, `count`= 1. 
The other thread calls `closeDb` and commpletes: the database is now closed, `count`= 0. 
The first thread completes `count++`: the database is still closed, `count`= 1. 
Thus an invalid state was created.

Comment: To avoid such race conditions you have use synchronization only

Comment: I am not sure I understand, what exactly you mean by this. Can you please explain? The code in your answer does not use any kind of syncronization I know of.